# Returning variables in Python Selenium from Javascript and updating them with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am currently using [Walmart's job site](https://jobs.walmart.com/us/login?jobId=688590-5022) and I'm trying to log in using Selenium with python. So far I am using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import argparse
import time
import traceback
import sys

while True:
        try:

            func_name = driver.find_element_by_id('extension_4').get_attribute('onkeyup')
            func_name = func_name[func_name.index(':')+1:]
            num = driver.execute_script('return ' + func_name)

            #js_functions.append(num)

            print repr(num)

        except NoSuchElementException: 
            exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            traceback.print_exc()

        except NoSuchWindowException:  # No Need to Continue if User closes Window
            break;

        try:
            driver.execute_script('return username(arguments[0])', 'ikegwukc@yahoo.com')
        except WebDriverException:
            exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            traceback.print_exc()
        
        time.sleep(2)
```

When I print num from this line:

```
 num = driver.execute_script('return ' + func_name).
```

It prints the username and password. I then try to update the function given (for example username) with the following line:

```
driver.execute_script('return username(arguments[0])', 'test@yahoo.com')
```

it complains that there is no such function what am I doing wrong? I've been stuck on this for a few weeks now any guidance or solutions will really help me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a particular reason to use JS, selenium can do this for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(username_variable)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password_variable)
driver.find_element_by_id('event-submit').click()
```

Did you have some other issue?

Comment: This doesn't work. The reason why I mentioned JS is because it looks like those form variables are in javascript when I look at the source code.